# PyQt строки выпадающего меню QComboBox наезжают друг на друга

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, qt5, pyqt4

Когда в стиле объектов QComboBox меняю размер шрифта, строки в выпадающем меню начинают наезжать друг на друга. В голову не приходит возможная причина. Пытался найти возможное свойство стиля - междустрочный интервал, но не обнаружил такого в QT. Пробовал вообще убирать какие либо стили (использовать то, что "дают по умолчанию"), но при этом увеличить шрифт - та же проблема.
Используется PyQt5 с Python 3.4
[image: Скриншот QComboBox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каким образом меняете шрифт?

Если вот так установить размер шрифта, то работает нормально:

```
from PyQt5.Qt import QApplication, QComboBox

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    combo = QComboBox()
    combo.setStyleSheet("""color:yellow;background:blue;font-size:128pt;""")
    combo.addItems(["text 1", "text 2", "text 3"])
    combo.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Почему то не додумался использовать setStyleSheet для отдельного объекта. У меня стили применяются через файл css: 
`
    file_style = "modules/style.css"
    with open(file_style, 'r') as fh:
        app.setStyleSheet(fh.read())
`